# How to configure gradle that nested jar files must be stored without compression?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle

In my `gradle` configuration, I wanted to enforce that nested jar files must be stored without compression. In `Maven`, we can define the configuration like this below:

```
<build>
     <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <configuration>
                     <archive>
                         <compress>false</compress>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

My question, how to configure such configuration with gradle?

Comment: You mean like with `entryJarCompression`? https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:entryCompression

Comment: I have my doubts that the given configuration for Maven is working?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `entryCompression` attribute for the [jar](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:entryCompression), zip, ear and tar plugins (since at least gradle 5).

The actual propagation/configuration is specific to your `build.gradle`.